# md-autocomplete validations working only if floating label is present

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I need to implement required validation on `md-autocomplete`, but seems that the validation works only if `md-floating-label` attribute is present on the component. Anyone has faced such issue?

Answer (score 2):

I am using version 1.1.0-RC.d, the issue was validation was working but validation message(through `ng-messages`) was not being shown. The only way I found to make it work was keeping the `ng-messages` div outside of the `md-autocomplete` element and then the error message start showing. Then I had to style it to look like an error. Also had to use `ng-if="myForm.autocompleteFieldName.$touched"` to make sure the error showed only once the field was edited and tabbed out and not by default.